# Safetynet to Play Integrity migration - Google Cloud account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play, safetynet, google-play-integrity-api, safetynet-api

When we migrate from the SafetyNet Api to Google Play Integrity Api we need link a PlayStore application to the Google Cloud Project in the Google Play console.
For existing on production application should it be the same google cloud project in which safetyet's keys were created? Or can it be different/new Google Cloud project and it will not affect the existing clients? Does it  matter which account I will link?  What should I do if I lost the account which originally was used to created the SafetyNet API keys?

I search through Google's documentation but I have not found any information about this matter. I also have not used increased api usage quota.

Answer (score 1):

Those two API's are not dependent on each other.
I've tried same application with two different Google Cloud projects and got the same token response. So I believe the answer is yes - you can link a new Google Cloud Project to your application.